# How to populate user input strings to sqlite

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist, sqlite

I have this code that simply creates a list from user input. I want to load this into sqlite Db instead of list shown but am not conversant with Sqlite. please help
HERE IS THE CODE

```
listQ = []
while True:
    read = input("Type in a line. ").lower().split()
    for item in read:
        listQ.append( input("Type in a line. ") )
    for line in listQ:
        import sqlite3
        conn = sqlite3.connect('/C/project/new/sqlite_file.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        for item in listQ:
        c.execute('insert into tablename values (?,?,?)', item)
        #print(line)
```

Comment: Did you create DB file? What is the table schema?

Comment: 1. You need to make the table in the db if you havent already. 2. You need to call `.commit()` to actually put the values into the database on disk (otherwise its put in a `.db-journal`). 3. your imports should be at the top of your file instead of in a loop being called multiple times.

Comment: Thanks Ninja, am learning this . lemi try